# moving cursor to a particular position in a series of number?

Tags: excel, vba

how to select a set of numbers fro ma series of number in excel macro? say i want to select the number from 5th position to 9th position number from "16964926469263"?

--
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sNumber As String
    Dim StartNumber As Long
    Dim EndNumber As Long

    Number = "16964926469263"

    StartNumber = 5
    EndNumber = 9

    Debug.Print Mid(Number, StartNumber, EndNumber - StartNumber + 1)
End Sub
```

This will give you `49264`

If you want before the 9th Position then use

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sNumber As String
    Dim StartNumber As Long
    Dim EndNumber As Long

    Number = "16964926469263"

    StartNumber = 5
    EndNumber = 9

    Debug.Print Mid(Number, StartNumber, EndNumber - StartNumber)
End Sub
```

This will give you `4926`